# how to add details from a json object to an svg?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, svg

I have an svg file of a competition certificate prepared in illustrator. I also have json objects which contain the name of the participants and their rank respectively. How do I parse this data from the json objects and add it to the svg to generate the complete certificate for every individual with all the details?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included what languages you wish to use, and how you have tried so far to do this.

Comment: I'm actually doing this for the first time. I'm basically trying to automate the process of certificate generation, that we get after the completion of a course, like that of coursera. How do I insert dynamic data into predesigned certificate template for every participant? I'm working with Angular to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612766/angular-6-not-able-to-add-text-on-canvas-dynamically answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936842/is-there-any-easy-way-to-assign-json-data-to-svg-element-using-javascript